# Subscript out of range when copying to cell

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to extract Data from emails by using this script I found online with some changes to run for my specific information:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim vText As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\Rob\Documents\Excel\ExcelTest.xlsx" 'the path of the workbook

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Process each selected record
rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.Body
    vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
    rCount = rCount + 1

    'Check each line of text in the message body
    For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
        If InStr(1, vText(i), "Destination -") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If
    Next i

    xlWB.Save
Next olItem
xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
    xlApp.Quit
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

The information I have to extract from the emails are shown below in BOLD.

Destination State - Pennsylvania

**Destination - Pittsburgh**

UK Airport - London Gatwick

Airline - United Airlines

**Flight Class - Premium - from £499**

**Depart Date - 27/07/2011**

Return Date - 10/08/2011

Adults - 2

Children - 1

**First Name - Andrew**

**Last Name - Leakey**

**Telephone - 07785 496123** // Number Is fake

**Contact Email - AmdrewsEmail@Email.org.uk**

When I run the code it says "Subscript out of range" and the debugger says it is occurring on this line.

```
xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
```

Comment: you split the  on chr(58) which is :, maybe there is no : il the line?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
   vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
```

with this:

```
  vItem = Split(vText(i),"-")
```